# How do i refresh a tableview after returning from Background

Tags: ios4, ip

How do I refresh a tableview after returning from Background(when the user hit home button and comes back later). Its not calling the viewWillApper delegate method.

Thanks,
Shinto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override applicationDidBecomeActive or applicationWillEnterForeground in the appDelegate.  Then I would either call the table view controller to reload or use a NSNotification.

Note:  applicationDidBecomeActive is also called when the app launches.  See: [Understanding iOS 4 Backgrounding and Delegate Messaging](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/)

Answer (score 0):

u can do it in the Home Button. First Get the ViewController thats hold the TableView and do further action...